# Emacs, moving point to first visible character

Tags: emacs, move

Is there any way to move point to the first **currently visible** character within a buffer? I would like to find this point because for a function it would really be faster to look from "first visible character" instead of "beginning of buffer".

EDIT: Actually, obtaining the value of the position would also be fine instead of moving the point actually there. PageUp and PageDown seem to have some weird behavior with this with big pieces of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the point the current window is scrolled to:

```
(window-start)
```

If you want to skip over text that is hidden by text attributes, use `invisible-p` to skip past them:

```
(let ((pos (window-start)))
  (while (and (invisible-p pos) (< pos (point-max)))
    (setq pos (1+ pos)))
  pos)
```

Comment: My answer for completeness, though I'll award you for partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

nschum gives the answer to obtaining the position value by: `(window-start)`

For moving point to this value use:

Based on [nschum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247380/1575066)'s answer:

```
(defun goto-window-start ()
 (interactive)
 (let ((pos (window-start)))
  (while (and (invisible-p pos) (< pos (point-max) )
   (setq pos (1+ pos)))
 (goto-char pos))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Handles empty buffer.

```
(defun goto-first-visible ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (save-match-data 
    (let ((pos (search-forward-regexp (rx graphic) nil t))) 
      (when pos 
        (goto-char (- pos 1))))))
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant **currently visible** (at least this isn't working, it stays at the beginning of buffer)

Comment: I think the OP means skipping text where `invisible-p` returns non-nil rather than whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient version that may work better for large chunks of invisible text.  The hack here is to use the fact that invisible text is controlled by text properties, and emacs has built-in facilities for determining locations of text property changes:

```
    (defun goto-first-visible ()
      (interactive)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (and (not (eobp)) (invisible-p (point)))
        (goto-char (next-char-property-change (point)))))
```